# sanitize-html changing ampersand in URL

Tags: node.js, url, encoding, html-sanitizing

I am using [sanitize-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) to sanitise html input before saving to a database.

The following:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is returned as:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The `&` in the href value has been changed to `&amp;`, which is ignored by some browsers and therefore changes the destination of the URL:

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&amp;display=swap`

!=

`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap`

Per the warnings [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html) I don't want to change the `decodeEntities` setting and I would want `&` to be encoded as `&amp;` in text content.

Is there a setting in sanitize-html that lets me (safely) preserve URLs? Or an alternative approach which doesn't involve re-parsing the HTML after it has been sanitised?

**Edit**

This is a [documented behaviour](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html/issues/151) of the library. Per [this page](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html/issues/151), the browser will use the correct value when a link is clicked. I assume this is also the case for `href` attributes that aren't clicked (e.g. in `<link>` tags), but don't know for sure?